# Why MacOS QML TextField with Password echo mode allows non-ascii(korea lanaguage) IME input?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

i use qt5.12.6
I recently ran into a strange problem while coding.(I am Korean)
QML TextField echoMode: TextInput.Password.

Windows platform not allows non-ascii(korea lanaguage) IME input.
but MacOS platform allows non-ascii(korea lanaguage) IME input.

why?
echoMode: TextInput.Password, is Properties Windows platform specific? Or am I missing a setting?

```
Window {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: "window"

  Column {
   width:  parent.width
   height: parent.height
  spacing: 10

   TextField {
    id: test
    echoMode: TextInput.Password
    width: 200
   }
   Text {
    id: test2
    width: 200
    text: test.text
   }
 }
}
```

[from MacOS, example code result(allows non-ascii[korea lanaguage] IME input)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYOKz.png)

if password textfield focus true, macos auto change IME input lanauage
I want it to be like the picture below.
[from dbeaver password focus true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9rHO.png)

I hope from MacOS platform not allows non-ascii IME input.
help me please...!
Thanks you

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Qt on macOS, and @stephen-quan answer is a good work-around for it. Looks like you already filed a bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-106250

Comment: @talamaki yeah. I myself uploaded this bug(QTBUG-106250) if It may not be a bug, to get advice.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than leave it to chance, you can control the allowable input with validators. For instance:

```
   TextField {
       id: test
       echoMode: TextInput.Password
       width: 200
       validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /[0-9A-Za-z]+/ }
   }
```

The above RegExpValidator will limit input to only alphanumeric characters.

Reference:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-regexpvalidator.html

Comment: thanks for answer me. but I know already validator. I want, if textfiled(echomode password) focus is true, Macos auto switching english lanaguage IME input